# Move all text values with the same ID field to separate columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to move all the comments **(Column B3:B14)** to be new columns against each unique ID **(Column A3:A14)**.

The Desired Format shows the layout that I would like to get to.

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Do you only want to do it as a one-off, or do you want to do it regularly? Also do you want to keep a copy of the original data the way it is and "display" it elsewhere like you have shown? Or do you actually want to modify the dataset?

Comment: @NelliNoodle - I will just need to run this 1 or 2 more times really. I don't need the original no as I can copy it it into another spreadsheet. The original data can stay where it is for reference to compare if everything copied across

Comment: Since you have commented that you have a Mac, and would prefer formulas, please show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. Also we must know what version of Excel you are using.  Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This will do what you want using vba:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeComments()

    Dim inSR%, inTR%, inTC%, rgSource As Range, rgTarget As Range
    
    Set rgSource = Range("A3")  'Change this if the 1st ID in the source table is moved
    Set rgTarget = Range("D3")  'Change this to start populating at another start point
    inTR = -1
    
    Do
        If rgSource.Offset(inSR) <> rgSource.Offset(inSR - 1) Then
            inTR = inTR + 1: inTC = 2
            rgTarget.Offset(inTR) = rgSource.Offset(inSR)
            rgTarget.Offset(inTR, 1) = rgSource.Offset(inSR, 1)
            
        Else
            rgTarget.Offset(inTR, inTC) = rgSource.Offset(inSR, 1)
            inTC = inTC + 1
        End If
        
        inSR = inSR + 1
    
    ''' End on 1st empty ID (assumes ID's in source data are contiguous and nothing is below them)
    Loop Until rgSource.Offset(inSR) = ""

End Sub
```

I've assumed you know how to implement and call/run the vb. If not, let me know and I try and help with that. :)

============================================================
EDIT: How to do it all with formulas?
I'm unsure of how dynamic the extraction table has to be (as you don't say). For example:
o  Will you be making a new extraction each time or will build a standing extractor table
o  Will the source data vary in size (so you need to grow and shrink the 'lookup' range)
o  Etc.

Given this, I've aimed for a solution that works and is adaptable. I'll leave it to you to adapt as appropriate

To extract the unique serial numbers:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$2:E2, $A$2:$A$14), 0)),"")}
```

To extract the corresponding comments:

```
{=IF($E3="","",IF(SUM(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E3,1))>=COUNTA($F$2:F$2),INDEX($B$2:$B$15,MATCH($E3,$A$2:$A$15,0)+COUNTA($F$2:F$2)-1),""))}
```

Notice the {}. Both are array formulas (entered with Ctrl, Shift and Enter)

Pictogram:
[image]

Addition Information:
The solution proposed assumes any same-serial-numbers are contiguous (as shown in your example.
If that's not the case by default, you'll have to sort the source date so it is.

Comment: Thanks Spinner, I really appreciate your effort in the above but I do not know how to run VB, plus I have a Macbook. Is this translatable into a formula?

Comment: @David: Have added a formula-based solution.

Comment: @David: Also, for any future questions you may ask: Including more detail upfront is only reasonable, given you're basically asking people to do work for you for free. e.g. saying you're only seeking a formula-based solution only, that you're using a mac, whether this is a one-time build or if you have to build it each time, etc. saves wasted effort on the part of people who may wish to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let

//read in the data
//change table name in next line to actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Comments", type text}}),

//group by ID and concatenate the comments with a character not used in the comments
//I used a semicolon, but that could be changed
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Comment", each Text.Combine([Comments],";")},

//also generate Count of the number of comments in each ID group
//as the Maximum will be the count of the number of columns to eventually create
        {"numCols", each Table.RowCount(_)}    
        }),

//calculate how many columns to create and delete that column
    maxCols = List.Max(#"Grouped Rows"[numCols]),
    remCount = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows","numCols"),

//Split into new columns
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(remCount, "Comment", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),maxCols)
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365 on the Mac with the `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, you can use:

```
D23: =UNIQUE(Table1[ID])  *or some other cell8
```

and in the adjacent column:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Table1[Comments],Table1[ID]=D23))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron but unfortunately I have a Macbook so I don't believe I have the Power Query functionality. Is this translatable into a formula?

Comment: @DavidCraven No, it is not. My understanding is the the current version of Excel in Office 365 can run on a Mac, but authoring is not supported.  So you would need to create a VBA routine to author your PQ on the Mac.  Probably you'd need access to a windows machine for that.

Comment: @DavidCraven See my edited answer for a formula solution if you have Excel for Microsoft 365 on your Mac